# Appending user variables to a list in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to add fruits to a list depending on the value of the variable `add_fruits`. I think I am on the right path, but in trying to append each `fruits` to the list I am getting an error. :(

```
fruits = []
add_fruits = int(raw_input("How many types of fruit do you have?"))
count = 0
while count < add_fruits:
    fruits = raw_input("Enter a fruit")
    count +=1
print fruits
```

Comment: Tell us what error you are getting, not just "I am getting an error."

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Assignment won't do an append operation on a list. You need to call `list.append()` function.

```
fruits.append(raw_input("Enter a fruit: "))
```

Comment: Thanks. Easy when you know how :)

Comment: Easy if you follow the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: So. Many.Tutorials. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same name for two different jobs; either `fruits` is the list, or `fruits` is the value the user entered.

Use a different name for the `raw_input()` return value, so you don't end up trying to append `fruits` to `fruits`:

```
while count < add_fruits:
    a_fruit = raw_input("Enter a fruit")
    fruits.append(a_fruit)
    count +=1
```

Rather than use a `while` loop, you could also use a `for` loop looping over the `xrange()` object; it'll iterate exactly `add_fruits` times:

```
fruits = []
add_fruits = int(raw_input("How many types of fruit do you have?"))
for count in xrange(add_fruits):
    a_fruit = raw_input("Enter a fruit")
    fruits.append(a_fruit)
print fruits
```